# ExtJS disable Treelist hover

Tags: extjs

How can I disable the hover events of an ExtJS treelist component (in micromode) so that the floater is only opened by a click/touch and not on hover/mouseover/mouseenter.

(Using ExtJS 6.2 Classic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This overriding the element config did the trick.

```
Ext.define('Admin.view.main.TreeList', {
extend: 'Ext.list.Tree',
requires: [
],
xtype: 'pdmtreelist',
ui: 'navigation',
micro:true,
expanderFirst: false,
expanderOnly: true,

element: {
    reference: 'element',
    listeners: {
        click: 'onClick',
        mouseenter: 'onMouseEnter',
        // mouseenter: Ext.emptyFn,
        // mouseover: Ext.emptyFn,
        mouseleave: 'onMouseLeave',
    },
    children: [{
        reference: 'toolsElement',
        listeners: {
            mouseover: Ext.emptyFn
            //mouseover: 'onToolStripMouseOver'
        }
    }]
}



});
```